# GRU in Tensorflow 1.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to implement a GRU for sentiment analysis and this is what I have so far:

```
epochs = 20
batch_size = 25
embedding_size = 50
layers = 1
max_label = 2  # only valid target labels are 0 and 1

# one word is fed in at any time instance
embedding_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, x)

# number of neurons in a single LSTM cell is equal to the embedding size
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(embedding_size)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell, output_keep_prob=0.75)

# encoding fed into softmax prediction layer
output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embeddings, dtype=tf.float32)

logits = tf.layers.dense(output, max_label, activation=None)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

# prediction is accurate if predicted label is equal to the actual label
prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.cast(y, tf.int64))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction, tf.float32))
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 1) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 3).
```

I tried changing the value of max_label to 2 and 1 and tried to make logits=logits-1 but the error is still there. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

*NB: This is without knowing the size of your label vector `y` nor which line the error message is coming from. Please include this important information in future questions.*

According to the tensorflow 1.3 docs, the usage of nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is:

"... to have logits of shape [batch_size, num_classes] and labels of shape [batch_size]. But higher dimensions are supported."

From my experience with using RNN's in tensorflow, the size convention of your model will be [Batch, Length of Sequence, Feature Size]. So, your output will be 3 dimensional. According to the quote I've attached above, your output should then be of size [Batch, Length of Sequence], with each value being the index of your label (so if position (X,Y) is class 30, then, in your code, y[X,Y] = 30). This is different (from my memory) to the non-sparse version, which takes in one-hot (or multiple-hot) encodings.